# Whats the best way to integrate 2 different react projects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-chat-engine

I Have a huge react project which requires a chat app.
I've now already made this chat app using react-chat-engine.

Now I want to integrate this chat app with the Main app. I can put it in the same app and route to it sure.. but...

I would like to use the same chat app for another application which will use similar database.

Other than iFrame and <a href.. is there any other way? Which is hopefully quicker to load

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `React.DOM.render(<App>,  document.getElementById("root"))` on different div then `#root` and you should have two react apps in one HTML